# Can't delete multiple rows from MySQL table in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, delete-row, corresponding-records

I'm trying to delete all the rows matching a pair of conditions from a mySQL table using php's PDO object. I can't figure out why it isn't working:

```
//This deletes all comments for a given post;
//Querying database for existent comments on that post;
$this->query = $this->db->query(
"SELECT cid 
FROM comments
WHERE id = '$html_data->id' AND pid = '$html_data->pid'"
);
//Fetching results into an array;
$this->rows = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//Deleting each comment on that post;
foreach ($this->rows as $this->row) {
    $this->db->exec(
    "DELETE from comments 
    WHERE cid = '$this->row['cid']'"
    );
};
//Deleting the post itself;
$this->db->exec(
"DELETE from posts 
WHERE id = '$html_data->id' AND pid = '$html_data->pid'"
);
```

`//Deleting the post itself` works, but the part inside the `foreach` loop doesn't for some reason. For debugging I added the following inside the loop:

```
echo "WHERE cid = '{$this->row['cid']}'";
```

And it returned just as expected:

```
WHERE cid = '1'
WHERE cid = '2'
```

So the data that is being fetched isn't the issue. I also tried

```
WHERE id = '$html_data->id' AND pid = '$html_data->pid' AND cid = '$this->row['cid']'"
```

Instead of using just the `cid` and it also didn't work. Echoing it returns, as expected:

```
WHERE id = '1' AND pid = '1' AND cid = '1'
WHERE id = '1' AND pid = '1' AND cid = '2'
```

And yes, I checked the `comments` table, `id`, `pid` and `cid` that I want to delete matches those that are being echoed.

Comment: Just `var_dump()` the query, look for double quotes or single quotes, because there are times when they are not present or just `var_dump()` the query and the go to phpmyadmin and paste the query into the query tab it will show what kind of errors you have, also `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id=1` already loopes through all the records in the table

Comment: So, your problem has nothing to do with mysqli but just with basic PHP syntax (and improper use of $this keyword). Yet another too localized question to pollute the site

Comment: Obviously I wasn't aware what the issue was, for me it was a problem with using PDO/mySQL inside a loop, since the code outside was almost identical and was working. But I'll consider using Code Review or some other website next time, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
$this->db->exec(
"DELETE from comments 
WHERE cid = '$this->row[cid]'"
);
```

OR you can also use

```
$this->db->exec(
"DELETE from comments 
WHERE cid = '{$this->row['cid']}'"
);
```

Comment: Your second approach worked, thanks. That's odd, since the query below `//Deleting the post itself` works just fine and I didn't need to use {}.

Answer (score 2):

So the better way of solving this problem is to use prepared statements and get the variables away from the queries. That way, you both solve this problem as well as fix security issues (SQL Injection) that you have right now...

Here's your code converted into efficient prepared statements:

```
$stmt= $this->db->prepare(
    "SELECT cid 
    FROM comments
    WHERE id = ? AND pid = ?"
);
$this->query = $stmt->execute(array($html_data->id, $html_data->pid));

$this->rows = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$deleteStmt = $this->db->prepare(
    "DELETE from comments 
    WHERE cid = ?"
);
foreach ($this->rows as $row) {
    $deleteStmt->execute(array($row['cid']));
};

//Deleting the post itself;
$stmt = $this->db->prepare(
    "DELETE FROM posts
    WHERE id = ? AND pid = ?"
);
$stmt->execute(array($html_data->id, $html_data->pid));
```

However, you can clean it up even further. The best way to deal with this is to use foreign keys. For example, let's create a foreign key from our comments table's `pid` to the posts `id` field.

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id   INT,
    name VARCHAR(35),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE comments (
    id   INT,
    pid  INT,
    name VARCHAR(35),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `posts_id`
    FOREIGN KEY `posts_id` (`pid`)
    REFERENCES `posts` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

The beauty here is that your big block of code up there reduces to just this:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare(
    "DELETE FROM posts
    WHERE id = ? AND pid = ?"
);
$stmt->execute(array($html_data->id, $html_data->pid));
```

When you delete the comment, the constraint (foreign key) will automatically cascade that delete to delete the comments as well (because if it didn't, there would be an invalid constraint)...